# jquery Dialog is not closing

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery modal dialog which is getting created dynamically:

```
 $("#body").append(("<div class=openDialog id= newdialog><div id=dialogbody></div></div>"));
$('#newdialog').dialog(
   {
       autoOpen: false,
       dialogClass: "no-close",
       modal: true,
       width: 400,
       height: 375,
       resizable: false,
       closeOnEscape: false
   });
```

After this I am rendering a partial view to this dialog

```
$('#newdialog').dialog('open');
    $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/controller/Add",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#dialogbody').html(data);
                    }
                });
```

But when I try to close this dialog with the following, it's not getting closed:

```
$('#newdialog').dialog('close');
```

So I tried the following, and it's getting closed:

```
$('#newdialog').parent('div').remove();
$('#newdialog').closest('.div').remove();
$("#newdialog").dialog('destroy').remove();
```

But after this, the parent pages controls will be non editable.

If I remove

```
closeOnEscape: false
```

and I press ESC again after closing it will be editable...

Any one have any clue/ suggestion to overcome this issue?

Comment: @Matt I removed the comma from the dialog when I just edited it

Comment: Do you see an errors in console section of Dev tools

Comment: @Scott, without the comma[closeOnEscape: false] also same thing..

Comment: @Sushanth, I checked via Dev tool both after closing via ESC[ with that i could get an editable page] and with out that and there is not any single difference in HTML

Comment: What browser you are using. Because I just tried it on chrome. It works fine.

Comment: @rozar,'was trying with IE9

Comment: Where are you calling `.dialog("close")`?

Comment: is it some thing to do with jQuery Versions? i was trying with 
Jquery-1.8.3 and 
Jquery UI-1.8.20

Comment: @Jasen -in the popUp , i have a close Button, from that button click , i am calling the .dialog("close")

Comment: So you're creating the button within the partial view that gets loaded in `$('#dialogbody').html(data)`? Does the button respond to the click event e.g. alert()?

Comment: @Jasen -yes, it will respond to the click event.

Comment: One more Update if I dont Have the Ajax Call then Div is working as Expected...

Answer (score 0):

I have got an alternative solution for this.

1.Instead of Creating all the time Dynamic div place one div, and next time if its not exists Create it.
and

$(document).ready(function () {

```
     $("#btnCreate").click(function () {
         if ($('#newdialog).length == 0) {
             alert('missing');
             $("#body").append("<div id=newdialog title=Add Product style=overflow: hidden;background-color:Yellow;border-bottom-width:5;background-color:Red></div>");
         }
         InitializeDialog($("#newdialog"));

         $("#newdialog").dialog("open");
     });



     //Method to Initialize the DialogBox
     function InitializeDialog($element) {


         $element.dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             width: 400,
             resizable: true,
             draggable: true,
             title: "Product Operation",
             model: true,

             closeOnEscape: false,
             open: function (event, ui) {
                 //Load the Partial View Here using Controller and Action
                 $element.load('/Prodcontroller/AddProduct');
             },

             close: function () {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             }

         });

     }
 });");
```

and closing time

$('#departmentdialog').dialog('close');

```
$('#newdialog).parent('div').remove();
$('#newdialog).closest('.div').remove();
```

this worked for me... Thanks every One